# Convert String to Int checking for overflow

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

When I tried to convert a very long integer to `Int`, I was surprised that no error was thrown:

```
Prelude> read "123456789012345678901234567890" :: Int
-4362896299872285998
```

`readMaybe` from `Text.Read` module gives the same result.

Two questions:

- Which function should I call to perform a safe conversion?
- How can the most type safe language on Earth allow such unsafe things?

**Update 1:**

This is my attempt to write a version of `read` that checks bounds:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

parseIntegral :: forall a . (Integral a, Bounded a) => String -> Maybe a
parseIntegral s = integerToIntegral (read s :: Integer) where
  integerToIntegral n | n < fromIntegral (minBound :: a) = Nothing
  integerToIntegral n | n > fromIntegral (maxBound :: a) = Nothing
  integerToIntegral n = Just $ fromInteger n
```

Is it the best I can do?

Answer (score 3):

#### Background: why unchecked overflow is actually wonderful

Haskell 98 leaves overflow behavior explicitly unspecified, which is good for implementers and bad for everyone else. Haskell 2010 discusses it in two sections—in the section inherited from Haskell 98, it's left explicitly unspecified, whereas in the sections on `Data.Int` and `Data.Word`, it is specified. This inconsistency will hopefully be resolved eventually.

GHC is kind enough to specify it explicitly:

> All arithmetic is performed modulo 2^n, where n is the number of bits in the type.

This is an extremely useful specification. In particular, it guarantees that `Int`, `Word`, `Int64`, `Word32`, etc., form rings, and even [principal ideal rings](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_ring), under addition and multiplication. This means that arithmetic will always work right—you can transform expressions and equations in lots of different ways without breaking things. Throwing exceptions on overflow would break all these properties, making it much more difficult to write and reason about programs. The only times you really need to be careful are when you use comparison operators like `<` and `compare`—fixed width integers do not form ordered groups, so these operators are a bit touchy.

#### Why it makes sense not to check reads

Reading an integer involves many multiplications and additions. It also needs to be fast. Checking to make sure the read is "valid" is not so easy to do quickly. In particular, while it's easy to find out whether an addition has overflowed, it is *not* easy to find out whether a multiplication has. The only sensible ways I can think of to perform a checked read for `Int` are

1. Read as an `Integer`, check, then convert. `Integer` arithmetic is significantly more expensive than `Int` arithmetic. For smaller things, like `Int16`, the read can be done with `Int`, checking for `Int16` overflow, then narrowed. This is cheaper, but still not free.
2. Compare the number *in decimal* to `maxBound` (or, for a negative number, `minBound`) while reading. This seems more likely to be reasonably efficient, but there will still be *some* cost. As the first section of this answer explains, there is nothing *inherently* wrong with overflow, so it's not clear that throwing an error is actually better than giving an answer modulo 2^n.

Comment: Some minor comments: saying `read` needs to be fast is a bit odd, as `read` is generally considered quite slow. It is not easy to check whether an arbitrary multiplication has overflowed from within Haskell, but a multiplication by ten ought to be easy to check (just see if the sign changed).

Comment: @DanielWagner, you're right; `read` is considered slow. Perhaps we should fix that. And I guess you're probably right about the multiplication by ten, in this context, but I need to think about that a bit more.

Comment: It's true that `Int` is a modular arithmetic type but usually people choose it as a more efficient Integer, or because it is the type used by List functions, not because they actually want modular arithmetic behavior.

Comment: @ReidBarton, they want cheaper integers, yes, but I imagine they don't want to have to reassociate or distribute operations to avoid overflow exceptions!

Comment: They probably do want exceptions on overflow.

Comment: Ada and a recent proposal to C (I think) have something interesting called "as if infinitely ranged" integers which seems to avoid some of the worries about exactly how you write expressions to avoid overflow, though I couldn't understand exactly what the semantics were supposed to be.

Comment: @ReidBarton, I think "I couldn't understand exactly what the semantics were supposed to be" is a pretty serious indictment compared to the straightforward semantics of unchecked overflow. However, I *would* like to see good tools for finding out when overflow has occurred; doing so for multiplication in general (if not in this case) is quite horrible.

Comment: @dfeuer I think that statement about `Int`/`Int16` is not true - I think you have to take the detour via `lnteger` (unless you already know your `String` is in the range of `Int`) - here an example `read (show $ 2 * (fromIntegral (maxBound :: Int) :: Integer)) :: Int` this is an Int overflow but  after flowing `-2` is in the range of `Int16`.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, I guess what I wrote was pretty severely unclear. The actual point is that you can perform the read *manually* (digit by digit), accumulating an `Int` value, and check for overflow along the way. So you read a digit, multiply the accumulator by ten, add the digit, and then test whether the accumulator lies within the `Int16` bounds. Rinse and repeat. This avoids all the allocation involved in reading `Integer` values (and, blast, reminds me that I really need to put together a PR implementing Bertram Felgenhauer's improved `Integer`-reading technique).

Comment: Ahh now I get you! Though I've never heard of felgenhauer ;)

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, he goes by "int-e" online.

Answer (score 2):

If isn't "unsafe", in that the behaviour of the problem isn't undefined. (It's perfectly *defined*, just probably not what you wanted.) For example, `unsafeWriteAray` is unsafe, in that if you make a mistake with it, it writes data into arbitrary memory locations, either causing your application to segfault, or merely making corrupt its own memory, causing it behave in arbitrary *undefined* ways.

So much for splitting hairs. If you want to deal with such huge numbers, `Integer` is the only way to go. But you probably knew that already.

As for why there's no overflow check... Sometimes you actually *want* a number to overflow. (E.g., you might convert to `Word8` without explicitly ANDing out the bottom 8 bits.) At any rate, every possible arithmetic operation can potentially overflow (e.g., `maxBound + 1 = minBound`, and that's just normal addition.) Do you really want every single arithmetic operation to have an overflow check, slowing your program down at every step?

You get the exact same behaviour in C, C++ or C#. I guess the difference is, in C# we have the `checked` keyword, which allows you to automatically check for overflow. Maybe somebody has a Haskell package for doing checked arithmetic… For now, it's probably simpler to just implement this one check yourself.

Comment: *It is* unsafe. Please, give me an example of a real world application, where `"123456789012345678901234567890"` should be parsed to `-4362896299872285998`? There is no such application. Exact same behavior in C#? This is absolutely not true. In C# `Convert.ToInt32` throws `OverflowException`. In Java `Integer.ParseInt` throws `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov 1. Nobody uses ``"12345678901234567890"`` with limited types such as ``Int32`` in C# or ``Int`` in Haskell (at least when dealing with code which requires security). 2. This behavior is absolutely and completely type safe because type safety does not automatically enforce semantic correctness. For example you can create instances of type classes which then type check but do not enforce the rules defined for instances of said class.

Comment: "Incorrect" and "unsafe" are not the same thing. Your code is incorrect if it gives you the wrong answer. It is only *unsafe* if it can actually crash the whole application, or corrupt main memory so that other unrelated parts of the application malfunction.

Comment: Incorrect is usually worse than `error`, since at least if you get an error you know that something went wrong. Real undefined behavior can in principle look like a successful execution if you are unlucky, but usually it just results in a crash.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov In C#, calling `Convert.ToInt32()` throws an exception. However, `(int)myLong` does *not* throw any exception. (One is a method call, the other is a type conversion. The *method* does a range-check; the *typecast* does not.) You are right, however, that (for example) `int.TryParse()` does a range check. Perhaps it would be helpful for Haskell's `read` method (only) to add this check...